# prepend elements properly on a carousel loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to fix an issue wherein the element pops in from the last to first position when I'm triggering the `previous` button on my carousel to prepend the element. I made a loop so that when I hit trigger the slider will slide first then the last element on the carousel will move from the last position to the first position. Unfortunately the transition isn't smooth if you check the code below. jquery `prepend` has a small delay before moving the last element from the last position to the first position. Is there a proper way to implementing the loop.

```js
(function ($) {
        'use strict';

        var carousel = {

            init : function() {

                var carouselWidth = 0,
                    itemListContainer = $('.item-list').width(),
                    itemList = $('.carousel .item-list ul li'),
                    containerWidth = $('.carousel .item-list').innerWidth(),
                    browserWidth = $(window).width(),
                    itemWidth = itemList.outerWidth( containerWidth / 3 ),
                    itemSize = itemWidth.outerWidth();


                //Set Container Width
                $('.carousel .item-list ul').children().each(function() {
                    carouselWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
                    $('.carousel .item-list ul').outerWidth(carouselWidth);
                });


                var offset = itemSize * 3;
              

               // function dynamicItemWidth() {
               //      if ( $('body') <= 1024 ) {
               //          itemWidth = itemList.width( itemListContainer / 5 );
               //      }

               //      if ( $('body') <= 480 ) {
               //          itemWidth = itemList.width( itemListContainer / 2 );
               //      }

               //      if ( $('body') <= 320 ) {
               //          itemWidth = itemList.width( itemListContainer / 1 );
               //      }

               //  }

                // var itemWidth = itemList.width( browserWidth / 5 ),
                //     itemSize = itemWidth.width();

                $('.carousel .item-list ul').prepend( $('.carousel .item-list ul li:last') );

                $('.carousel .item-list ul').css('left', '-' +  itemSize + 'px'  );


                $('.btns .next').click(function(){

                    var move = $('.carousel .item-list ul li').outerWidth();
                    var leftIndent = parseInt($('.carousel .item-list ul').css('left')) - move;

                    function animate( repeat, speed ) {
                        $('.carousel .item-list ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : leftIndent}, speed,function(){
                            $('.carousel .item-list ul').append( $('.carousel .item-list ul li:first') );
                            $('.carousel .item-list ul').css({'left' : '-' +  move + 'px'});

                            if ( repeat > 1 ) {
                                animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed );                     }
                        });
                    }

                    animate( 1, 300 );

                });

                $('.btns .prev').click(function() {

                    var move = $('.carousel .item-list ul li').outerWidth();
                    var leftIndent = parseInt($('.carousel .item-list ul').css('left')) + move;

                    function animate( repeat, speed ) {
                        $('.carousel .item-list ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : leftIndent}, speed,function(){
                            $('.carousel .item-list ul').prepend($('.carousel .item-list ul li:last'));
                            $('.carousel .item-list ul').css({'left' : '-' + move + 'px'});

                            if ( repeat > 1 ) {
                                animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed );
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    animate( 1, 300 );

                });

            }

        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            carousel.init();
        });


        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            carousel.init();  
        })

    })(jQuery);
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   font: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
   display: block;
}

body {
   line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
   list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
   quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
   content: '';
   content: none;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* -- #Carousel -- */

.carousel {
   position: relative;
}

.carousel .item-list {
   max-width: 1366px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   box-sizing: content-box;
}

.carousel .item-list ul {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   list-style: none;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel .btns {
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 50%;
}

.carousel .btns li {
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel.-aim-partners {
   position: relative;
}

.carousel.-aim-partners .item-list {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel.-aim-partners .item-list ul li {
   float: left;
   width: 230px;
   height: 110px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   background-color: beige;
}

.carousel.-aim-partners .btns {
   width: 110%;
   left: -70px;
}

.carousel.-aim-partners .btns li {
   width: 35px;
   height: 40px;
}

.carousel.-aim-partners .btns li.prev {
   background: url("../images/carousel-icon-arrow.png") no-repeat 15px 0;
}

.carousel.-aim-partners .btns li.next {
   background: url("../images/carousel-icon-arrow.png") no-repeat -20px 0;
}

/* -- End Carousel -- */

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='carousel -aim-partners'>

      <div class='item-list'>
          <ul>
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
              <li>5</li>
              <li>6</li>
              <li>7</li>
              <li>8</li>
              <li>9</li>
              <li>10</li>
              <li>11</li>
              <li>12</li>
              <li>13</li>
              <li>14</li>
              <li>15</li>
              <li>16</li>             
              
          </ul>
      </div>


        <ul class="btns">
            <li class="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true">prev</i>
            </li>
            <li class="next">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true">next</i>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the expected output & what is the current output ?

Comment: @RohitasBehera currently when I hit the `previous` button the last element on the carousel will move from the last position to the first position. Unfortunately the transition isn't smooth, it shows an effect wherein the element will pop in. I need to element that.

Comment: @RohitasBehera Basically the jquery `prepend` has a small delay when triggering the `previous` button.

Answer (score 1):

Change the way you animate it can affect the view. Checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yq3b30ar/). I create a simple example with a different animation method.

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
  $('.slide li:last').css('width',0);
  $('.slide li:last').prependTo('.slide');
  $('.slide li:first').animate({width: '98px'});
});
```

Comment: Question: Why doesn't your next trigger `animate` but the `previous` animates when sliding?

Comment: It was working but not visible because width increase from left to right. You can see the effect by reducing the number of slides. However I added another method to the next button and now it is working. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/shalika247/eq0jL7qg/) the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/shalika247/eq0jL7qg/

Comment: Yah I've noticed that yesterday after inspecting the element